# .htacces not working as long as there is a file with the same name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

im trying to redirect some subdirectories to a processor in php to handle the Requests. 
Basicly, that means i want to redirect www.myurl.com/members/Max to urlprocessor.php?url=members/Max, so i can process it there an get the Member-Data i need.

Im using the following Code in my .htacces, which is working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /newboots
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^members(.*)$ urlprocessor.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But! As soon as there is a members.php in my directory, i get some Errors.
Calling /members/Max is still working.
Calling /members leads to a blank page.
Calling /members/ leads to a blank page.
Calling /members. is working
(Even) calling /members.php is working

As soon as i rename members.php to sometingelse.php it's working fine again.

I dont get it :)
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to options `MultiViews` being enabled in your Apache. Disable it by placing this line at the top:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Thanks alot!! Fixed the Problem - i would never have found this one :-)